# Most optimal algorithm for parsing string input

Tags: algorithm

Ok, algorithm wizzys. Let's assume you have this input:

The sky is blue[start]the sky is blue[end]The sand is brown[start]the sand is brown[end]The sky is blue and the sand is brown

You want to parse it based on the following rules:

1. Break the input into lines at the beginning and end of every [start] and [end] tag
2. Change value of blue to grey if it is between [start] and [end] tags
3. Change value of brown to tan if it is between [start] and [end] tags

The expected output should be exactly like shown below:

1. The sky is blue
2. [start]
3. the sky is grey
4. [end]
5. The sand is brown
6. [start]
7. the sand is tan
8. [end]
9. The sky is blue and the sand is brown

What would be an optimal algorithm to do this?

Note: It doesn't matter what language you use to respond, as long as the flow of thoughts is clear

Comment: This is better for codegulf.stackexchange.com StackOverflow is really more for specific questions and help

Answer (score 0):

You *could* create a context free grammar with [start], [end], blue, brown and everything-else as lexemes, build a parse tree, modify it and rebuild the string.

Seems like a bit of a stretch, though. Instead, do a search and replace, replace [start] with \n[start]\n and [end] with \n[start]\end. Then go over the lines, and on lines between start and end replace your colors.

Using a parser is much cooler, though.